# How to remove 'index.php' from browser URL while Joomla is hosted on IIS?

Tags: iis, joomla, joomla3.1

I am working on Joomla 3.1 and my Joomla project is hosted on IIS server. I am facing problem that index.php is coming in my url while i enable SEO configuration. I have enable all necessary configuration from joomla back-end.

can you please help me to remove index.php ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you have set **URL rewriting** to **Yes** in the Joomla backend? Also, try changing `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`

Comment: yes I am sure..also .htaccess does not work on IIS so i also make web.config file which has been given by Joomla package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip in the Global Configuration says:

```
Rename web.config.txt to web.config and
install IIS URL Rewrite Module before activating.
```

Have you done both?

I just tried, and I also made sure that the htaccess.txt file is renamed to .htaccess and that there is no web.config.txt and just the web.config file and it worked.
It didn't work before applying those changes, but I'm not sure that the htaccess file is relevant.

Comment: I install URL Rewrite Module in IIS and its done...work fine...I also got help from below URL. may be will help you in future.     http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-joomla-on-iis

Comment: Thanks for the link. My IIS came with the URL Rewrite Module pre-installed (or I didn't notice while installing) and I just had to manage the files to make it work.